# My DAX Measure for Custom Conditional Formatting In Power BI is not clickable

Tags: powerbi, dax, conditional-formatting

Please I need help with my Power BI custom conditional formatting. I created a DAX measure to help me color names of employees that are found in more than one team in day in Power Bi Matrix.

I tried applying the measure in conditional formatting but the measure is grayed out and not clickable. the image is attached below

[The measures for formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DTg6.png)

The DAX measure is below.

```
Technician Grouping = IF(SELECTEDVALUE('Technicians Name'[Names]) IN 
ALLSELECTED('view_register_teams'[team_number]), "#500805")
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the image you have posted, use the "Rules" option in place of "Field Value"

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work.
remember I have set the function in DAX level.